# Angular: How to get sibling directive value from directive?

Tags: angularjs

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdgr7e3t/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        {{test}}
        <form>
            <username></username>
            <submit></submit>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.test = "Greetings!"
}])
.directive("username", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){
            this.value = $scope.username;
        },
        template: "<div>username<input type='text' value='123' ng-model='username' /></div>"
    };
})
.directive("submit", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "username",
        link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl){
            ele.bind("click", function(){
                console.log(ctrl.value);
            });
        },
        template: "<div><input type='submit' value='submit' /></div>"
    };
});
```

I want to get username input value when submit button is clicked. What have I done wrong? 

Can somebody help me? 

Cheers!

Comment: have you checked the console? "Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'username', required by directive 'submit', can't be found!"

Comment: in other words, you are using the `require` option incorrectly in this case.

Comment: yes, that's why I ask about how to link with sibling directive.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=username&p1=submit

Comment: @Claies How to fix it? Can you give me a hand?

Comment: you can actually make use of the fact that both of them share the same scope. I updated the fiddle. check out if this helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/05f04gso/

Comment: You can't require a controller without a name.  add a controller called `username` if you want to require it.  you are trying to require the other directive, which isn't the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

require can only search itself or it's parents, scope would be easier, to avoid using scope , use require controller and u need to custom form as directive and both username and submit require it's controller